# Warnings when subclassing tensorflow.keras.utils.Sequence and using multiprocessing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I subclassed tensorflow.keras.utils.Sequence into a custom generator, since I use a large datasets stored in HDF5 files. Up to tensorflow 1.13, everything was okay... but after the update to TF2.2, it starts to spell "WARNING:tensorflow:multiprocessing can interact badly with TensorFlow, causing nondeterministic deadlocks. For high performance data pipelines tf.data is recommended."

If I set multiprocessing to False, ang get sequential reads, no warnings are given... but training gets painfully slow, since retrieving data from my generator were designed to take in account concurrent disk reads.

I found it hard-coded here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py#L521

How to convert an existing generator into tf.data? Or, there is a way to keep using my old handcrafted generator and don't get this nondeterministic behavior TF code claims?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot get rid of those warnings and while they can be annoying they do point you in the right direction.
Similar warnings occur if you also use `ImageDataGenerator()`.

I was also reticent at a point to switch to `tf.data.Dataset()`. Nevertheless it is truly cleaner and more efficient, and also easily scalable and not suffering from "multiprocessing issues".

Therefore I strongly recommend that you switch to `tf.data.Dataset()`.  To supress the warnings you may want to use the following snippet (also it does not guarantee that all warnings from `tf.*` will go away)

```
import logging, os

logging.disable(logging.WARNING)
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"
```

Documentation for `tf.data.Dataset()` : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset